# How to fix a compatibility problem with django and sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, django-2.0

I'm trying to add a project in my django admin panel, but get an OperationalError. I was searching and found that is a 
compatibility problem. How can i set other version of sqlite3 in my project?

I tried to install some other version of sqlite but doesn't work. I also search in the documentation of django and other pleases but nothing so far.

This is my Project model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField() . 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And this is the OperationalError:

> OperationalError at /admin/portfolio/proyect/add/
>   no such table: main.auth_user__old
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/portfolio/proyect/add/
>   Django Version: 2.0.2
>   Exception Type: OperationalError
>   Exception Value:
>   no such table: main.auth_user__old
>   Exception Location: /Users/carloseduardoloreshernandez/anaconda3/envs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 303
>   Python Executable:  /Users/carloseduardoloreshernandez/anaconda3/envs/django2/bin/python
>   Python Version: 3.7.4
>   Python Path:
>   ['/Users/carloseduardoloreshernandez/Desktop/Apps/Personal/Python/Django2-Udemy/Web '
>    'personal/Web-personal-Django2/Backend',
>    '/Users/carloseduardoloreshernandez/anaconda3/envs/django2/lib/python37.zip',
>    '/Users/carloseduardoloreshernandez/anaconda3/envs/django2/lib/python3.7',
>    '/Users/carloseduardoloreshernandez/anaconda3/envs/django2/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
>    '/Users/carloseduardoloreshernandez/anaconda3/envs/django2/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
>   Server time:    Dom, 15 Sep 2019 10:10:05 +0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it making a django upgrade:

```
pip install django --upgrade
```

then a migration:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

now all is working perfectly.